# Maxwell’s first equation in conductor we take E=0. And I have read that’s true for practical time scales. But in 4th equation we use non zero E, why?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-resistance, maxwell-equations

\begin{align}
\nabla\cdot E&=0\\
\nabla\cdot B&=0\\
\nabla\times E&=-\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}\\
\nabla \times B&=\mu J+\varepsilon\mu\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}=\mu\sigma E+\mu\frac{\partial D}{\partial t}
\end{align}

Is it because the 4th equation caused first equation?

Comment: Where have you assumed $E=0$?

Answer (score 0):

The first law is

$$\nabla \cdot E = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} $$

This must be a conductor with no excess charges. That is, in any volume there are just as many electrons as protons. So $\rho = 0$. Note that this assumption is true for a typical wire, but not for the plate of a capacitor.

However, the electrons can move, making a current. So $J$ doesn't have to be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $\vec E$ is zero inside a conductor is a result of *electrostatics*, where charges are assumed to be stationary. Your fourth equation uses the microscopic version of Ohm's law which by definition involves moving charges. You can't apply them both at the same time.